# SQL analytical query with number of matching assets

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to return a analytical query for a number of metrics for particular assets in one call, however not all assets have every metric.  So I want to also return the count of matching distinct assets per metric.

I have the following data structure

```
|--- asset ---|--- date ---|--- metric1 ---|--- metric2 ---|
| abc         | 2020-04-01 | 53            | <null>        |
| abc         | 2020-04-02 | 64            | <null>        |
| def         | 2020-04-01 | 22            | 15            |
| def         | 2020-04-02 | 89            | 42            |
| ghi         | 2020-04-01 | <null>        | 8             |
| ghi         | 2020-04-02 | <null>        | 92            |
| jkl         | 2020-04-01 | <null>        | 55            |
| jkl         | 2020-04-02 | <null>        | 36            |
```

The result I am after is

```
|--- metric1_sum ---|--- metric2_sum ---|--- metric1_asset_count ---|--- metric2_asset_count ---|
| 228               | 248               | 2                         | 3                         |
```

The only way I can think is to add sub queries for each metric e.g.

```
SELECT SUM(metric1) AS "metric1_sum",
       SUM(metric2) AS "metric2_sum",
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT asset) 
        FROM table 
        WHERE metric1 IS NOT NULL) AS "metric1_asset_count",
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT asset) 
        FROM table 
        WHERE metric2 IS NOT NULL) AS "metric2_asset_count"
FROM table
```

However when I scale this up too many metrics I have in the table ~10, the query time dramatically increases.

I am no SQL expert so is there a way to return the results I require in a reasonable response time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(metric1) AS metric1_sum,
       SUM(metric2) AS metric2_sum,
       count(distinct asset) filter (where metric1 is not null) as  metric1_asset_count,
       count(distinct asset) filter (where metric2 is not null) as  metric2_asset_count
FROM table
```